# How does ctypes library implement fundamental data type multiplication to generate arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, ctypes

In [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#arrays) there is an example showcasing code on how to create arrays where an object of type class is multiplied by an int.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> TenIntegers = c_int * 10
>>> ii = TenIntegers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
>>> print(ii)
<c_long_Array_10 object at 0x...>
```

In python3 shell, I have checked and confirmed that ctypes.c_int is type class.

```
>>> type(ctypes.c_int)
<class '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'>
```

I know that classes can define how operators behave with their class instances via dunder methods, but I have never seen definitions of behavior with the class objects themselves. I have tried checking the source code of ctypes, but I find it very difficult to understand it. Does anyone know how something like that could be implemented or how it is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python), for example:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...  def __mul__(self, other):
...   print(f"Multiplying {self} by {other}")  # Here you do something meaningful
...   return self  # As always, you can return whatever you please, not necessarily `self`
... 
>>> class SomeClass(metaclass=Meta):
...  ...
... 
>>> SomeClass * 10
Multiplying <class '__main__.SomeClass'> by 10
<class '__main__.SomeClass'>
```

As you correctly say, "classes can define how operators behave with their class instances via dunder methods". Any class is itself an instance of some metaclass (the metaclass of `type` is `type` itself), so the same principle holds with classes and metaclasses.